# Erro função barcode.php enquanto gero PDF com MPDF

Tags: php, html, css, pdf

Estou em um projeto na empresa de enviar o boleto daqui de uma forma automática pro e-mail dos clientes. O fato é que o layout e o boleto já estão funcionando perfeitamente.
O único problema é que, na hora de eu transformar o boleto para pdf de uma forma automática, ele dá o seguinte erro:

> "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\wamp\www\siclop-enviar_boleto\funcoes_itau.php:114) in C:\wamp\www\siclop-enviar_boleto\pdf\mpdf.php on line 8297"
>   "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\wamp\www\siclop-enviar_boleto\funcoes_itau.php:114) in C:\wamp\www\siclop-enviar_boleto\pdf\mpdf.php on line 1706"

Estou usando o `mPDF` e esse erro só acontece quando eu chamo a função de gerar o código de barras. Quando eu não chamo essa função, ele me mostra o pdf formatado porém obviamente não me mostra o código de barras (somente a linha digitável).
Não sei por que ele não entende o código de barras. Eu vi que no próprio `mPDF` tem uma classe chamada `barcode.php`; não sei se ele aceita o código de barras somente utilizando essa classe...

Gostaria de saber se vocês podem me ajudar com esse erro ou se tem alguma sugestão de como eu posso estar fazendo essa conversão para pdf?
O código da função de geração de código de barras é esse:

```
<?php 
function fbarcode($valor){

$fino = 1 ;
$largo = 3 ;
$altura = 50 ;

  $barcodes[0] = "00110" ;
  $barcodes[1] = "10001" ;
  $barcodes[2] = "01001" ;
  $barcodes[3] = "11000" ;
  $barcodes[4] = "00101" ;
  $barcodes[5] = "10100" ;
  $barcodes[6] = "01100" ;
  $barcodes[7] = "00011" ;
  $barcodes[8] = "10010" ;
  $barcodes[9] = "01010" ;
  for($f1=9;$f1>=0;$f1--){ 
    for($f2=9;$f2>=0;$f2--){  
      $f = ($f1 * 10) + $f2 ;
      $texto = "" ;
      for($i=1;$i<6;$i++){ 
        $texto .=  substr($barcodes[$f1],($i-1),1) . substr($barcodes[$f2],($i-1),1);
      }
      $barcodes[$f] = $texto;
    }
  }
//Desenho da barra
//Guarda inicial
?><img src=img/p.png width=<?php echo $fino?> height=<?php echo $altura?> border=0><img 
src=img/b.png width=<?php echo $fino?> height=<?php echo $altura?> border=0><img 
src=img/p.png width=<?php echo $fino?> height=<?php echo $altura?> border=0><img 
src=img/b.png width=<?php echo $fino?> height=<?php echo $altura?> border=0><img 
<?php
$texto = $valor ;
if((strlen($texto) % 2) <> 0){
    $texto = "0" . $texto;
}
// Draw dos dados
while (strlen($texto) > 0) {
  $i = round(esquerda($texto,2));
  $texto = direita($texto,strlen($texto)-2);
  $f = $barcodes[$i];
  for($i=1;$i<11;$i+=2){
    if (substr($f,($i-1),1) == "0") {
      $f1 = $fino ;
    }else{
      $f1 = $largo ;
    }
?>
    src=img/p.png width=<?php echo $f1?> height=<?php echo $altura?> border=0><img 
<?php
    if (substr($f,$i,1) == "0") {
      $f2 = $fino ;
    }else{
      $f2 = $largo ;
    }
?> src=img/b.png width=<?php echo $f2?> height=<?php echo $altura?> border=0><img 
<?php
  }
}
// Draw guarda final
?>src=img/p.png width=<?php echo $largo?> height=<?php echo $altura?> border=0><img 
src=img/b.png width=<?php echo $fino?> height=<?php echo $altura?> border=0><img 
src=img/p.png width=<?php echo 1?> height=<?php echo $altura?> border=0>  
?>
```

Comment: o código código acima é do arquivo `siclop-enviar_boleto\pdf\mpdf.php`?

Comment: Não. Este código é de outra página. Da funcoes_itau.php, que puxamos para a boleto_manual.php pelo include.

Comment: Nos arquivos intermediários (que são incluídos), você não pode fechar a tag `?>`. Na realidade, nenhum script PHP está se recomendando fazer isso senão gera o problema que recebeu. Veja se resolve por favor.